# Import dump file in Oracle 11g XE Linux OS

Tags: oracle11g

I need to import dump file which is exported from windows oracle 11g 32bit in Linux oracle 11g 64bit.

i tried:

imp USERID=user/pass FILE=DUMP.dmp FULL=y

but my table are not creating .

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
imp your_schema/<password>@<TNS Name> fromuser=<source> touser=<dest> file='c:\your_dump.DMP' ROWS=Y
```